# Validation 2 digits minimum C language

Tags: c, validation, passwords

My job is to make a password validator with:

1. No spaces allowed
2. 1 Symbol
3. 2 Digits
4. Minimum 6 characters
5. Maximum 10 characters

Just the above restrictions, so far I have done alone the `1`, `2`, `4`, `5` and I can't solve the third requirement about 2 digits. I can only do so with 1 digit so how do I to do it with 2? I think regex doesn't work like C++ and C# in C. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    char pass[11];
    int stop;

    printf("Give password:\n");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s",pass);

    do{
        if(strlen(pass)<6){
            stop=0;
            printf("Too short password.");
        }
        else if(strlen(pass)>10){
            stop=0;
            printf("Too long password.");
        }
        else if(strchr(pass, ' ')){
            stop=0;
            printf("No spaces.");
        }
        else if((strchr(pass, '$')==NULL && strchr(pass, '#')==NULL && strchr(pass, '@')==NULL && strchr(pass, '!')==NULL && strchr(pass, '%')==NULL && strchr(pass, '*')==NULL)){
            stop=0;
            printf("Must give at least one of $, #, @, !, %% or *.");
        }
        else{
            stop=1;
            printf("Your password is %s\n", pass);
        }
    }while(stop=0);

    return 0;}
```

Comment: Can you think of a way to count the digits?

Comment: Note: remove `s` from `(" %[^\n]s"`.  It is not needed.

Comment: Complex password rules will usually not lead to more safe passwords, important is only a minimum length. People cannot remember tons of strong passwords, and such rules can interfere with good password schemes. People can get very inventive to bypass such rules, e.g. by using weak passwords like "Password-2014". Often you end up with weaker passwords instead of stronger ones. In every case you should remove the upper limit of 10 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not really a [regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). What you have there is basically a small program that checks its input for different conditions. So, in the same manner, to make sure you have 2 digits, let's create a function that counts the number of digits. Keep in mind that in ASCII the digits 0 to 9 are in a continuous block (this is very important, as you will see).

```
int countDigits(char *input) {
    int digitCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++)      // for every character
        if (input[i] >= '0' && input[i] <= '9')  // if it is a digit
            digitCount++;
    return digitCount;
}
```

I've written this function this way to introduce show some character manipulation techniques. It would have been better if the condition would be:

```
if (isdigit(input[i]))
```

for portability reasons. Note that the function isdigit is defined in the ctype.h header. There is still some room for improvement:

```
int countDigits(char *input) {
    int digitCount = 0;
    int noOfCharacters = strlen(input);          // avoid strlen() being called
                                                 // for every iteration
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++)      // for every character
        digitCount += isdigit(input[i]);

    return digitCount;
}
```

Now you need just to take this function and check if it returns 2 for the input you've got.

Comment: `if (isdigit(input[i]))` is not better than `if (input[i] >= '0' && input[i] <= '9')` as `if (isdigit(input[i]))` is UB if `char` is signed.  Could use `if (isdigit((unsigned char) input[i]))`.

Comment: Okey, @Paul92 thanks, your answer made me think better! I thought this was regex.. because i saw some similar codes in C# and Java for validation and they do it with regex... anyway now i am ok its working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

- RegEx search `[^0-9]` the input string and replace  globally with nothing.
- Verify the remaining string to be two characters long.

Answer (score 0):

1. No reason for small-ish buffer.   Test #5 cannot have been done properly with `pass[11]`

   ```
   // char pass[11];
   char pass[100];
   ```
2. Dangerous to use unlimited length input.  Change to

   ```
   scanf(" %99[^\n]",pass);
   ```
3. Count the digits

   ```
   int cnt = 0;
   for (i=0; pass[i]; i++) {
     if (pass[i] >= '0' && pass[i] <= '9') cnt++;
   }
   if (cnt != 2) BadPsss();
   ```

Comment: Can you tell me why its dangerous to use unlimited length input? Also the small-ish buffer, i dont understand why 100? my string will be max 10 + \0 = 11 so pass[11] would be ok whats the problem?

Comment: @Sotnam96   I see you all ready have accepted an answer.  Hmmm.  Oh well.  How was code exercised to get the "Too long password."? Certainly something longer than 10 was entered like "12345678901".  This took 11  + 1 `char` to save, overfilling `char pass[11]`.  Your code did not crash, today, else you would have done something about that, but it _did_ overfill the buffer - corrupting who-knows-what.  So you need a buffer bigger than `pass[11]` to test is the string length > 10.

Comment: @Sotnam96 What is dangerous about `scanf(" %[^\n]",pass);`? Just what you experienced, a false sense of correct code.  Many security exploits from hackers take advantage of code like this.  There are many posts on SO concerning this hack.  Robust code guards against overrunning buffers.  Using `char pass[100]; … scanf(" %99[^\n]",pass);` as suggested, limits user input to 99 `char` as 99 + 1 (`‘\0’`) `char`could be saved.  Should a use enter more than 99 `char`, only up to 99 `char` would be read, leaving additional input still in `stdin`.  At least `pass` would not be over-filled.